# Trouble when I try to run Archive command in XCode

Tags: objective-c, facebook, sdk, archive

I'm making an app with Facebook validation.  It is working fine on simulator and in the device.

But, when I try to "Archive" (Product => Archive), I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lfacebook_ios_sdk
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The libraries are okay, otherwise it would not compile on simulator/device.

I don't know if this information is relevant, but my project is an ARC project.

Does anyone know what this error could mean?

Comment: You can post your answer as an answer the question if you'd like.

Comment: Yes! I could not do it before because I had to wait 7 hours before post an answer to myself.

Comment: Aha!  I didn't realize there is a time limit like that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by just removing the "libfacebook_ios_sdk.a" reference from my Link Binary Libraries and adding it again.

I dont know why it worked, but worked!